# 550 failed to change directory when trying to access a directory through web browser

Tags: linux

Hi i have been facing this problem for quite some time. Till now i still not able to solve it. Can Someone help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U5Kq.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pof9h.png

The vsftpd Configuration file

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

Local_umask=022

anon_upload_enable=YES

anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

listen=NO

listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd

userlist_enable+YES

tcp_wrappers=YES

Comment: It's probably a permission related issue. I don't know enough about which config settings to change to help solve your problem. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736743/ftp-550-failed-to-change-directory) question which seems to be the same issue. If you could add the text from `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` it may help someone know what you're missing. This may also be better suited for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). You'll probably get a better response there.

Comment: This is my directory permission https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt8JI.png when i try to change the permission it give me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuhEz.png